# mysql_query missing when installing pdo_mysql

Tags: php, pdo, centos

I am trying to install pdo_mysql on my CentOS server. I have PDO installed already; phpinfo() tells me that pdo_sqlite is active.

So I run the command

```
pecl install pdo_mysql
```

However, this errors out with the message

```
checking for MySQL support for PDO... yes, shared
checking for mysql_config... /usr/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_query in -lmysqlclient... no
configure: error: mysql_query missing!?
```

I've ensured that the extensions have been declared in my php.ini, also.

I've had a look around on the web and can't find anything to help.

Oh, and if it matters, I'm running PHP 5.3.3.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this PHP Bug yet? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36014&edit=1

Comment: any reason you aren't using yum? "yum install php-mysql"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post the solution here in case it helps others.

I tried running

```
yum install php-mysql
```

but kept receiving the error

```
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
```

Solution was simple (just not obvious to me at first) just run

```
yum install php53-mysql
```

Apache restart and PDO_mysql working.

Comment: Make sure to 'accept' your own answer by clicking the checkbox :)